# deduction theorem prove

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

Let $Λ$ be a set of all WFFs that are logical axioms.
Given a set $Γ$ of WFFs and a WFF $\theta$.

(A) Suppose we have some $k∈ℕ$ and $k$ WFFs $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,....,\alpha_k$ such that
$ Γ ⊢ $ $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,....,\alpha_k\}$, and $(\alpha_k \to(...\to(\alpha_2 \to \alpha_1 \to \theta))...)∈ Γ∪Λ $.

Prove that: $Γ ⊢ \theta$.

(B) Suppose that $Γ ⊢ \theta$, then exist some $k∈N$ and $k$ WFFs $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,....,\alpha_k$ such that $ Γ ⊢  \{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,....,\alpha_k\} $.

Prove that: $(\alpha_k \to(...\to(\alpha_2 \to \alpha_1 \to \theta))...)∈ Γ∪Λ $

(A) Proof: Obvious, via repeated applications of MP.

(B) Proof: We argue by induction on the minimal length n of a deduction of $\theta$.

Comment: Hint: use the deduction theorem

Comment: @RobinHouston How to prove B?

Comment: Are you sure about the statement of the problem ? What is the "opposite" of $A$: if $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, then ..." ? Consider as $\Gamma$ the set $\{ p \}$; clearly: $\Gamma \vdash p$ and the only possibility is $p \to p$, that is a tautology (and thus provable) but we do not know if it is an axiom...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I've edited B

Comment: What is $\Lambda$? What is the meaning of a _set_ of wffs to the right of $\vdash$ in the premises here?

Comment: "natural deduction" ? There are no logical axioms in ND.